# how to define a method that takes a generic type as parameter from certain parent class

Tags: java, android

I know that I can use Object as the parameter type , but then I have to cast to the class I want.

My question is: Can I do something like that

```
public void doSomething( <T extends Person> person ) { 
              Student student  =  person ;  
}
```

like what we can achieve with return type in java

```
public <T extends Person> T findPerson() { ;;;;;}
Student student =  findPerson(1) ;
```

English is not my native language, so sorry if the question is not clear enough

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like

```
public <T extends SomeClass> void doSomething(T item){
   //Do something
   item.number = 4;
}
```

Where:

```
class SomeClass{
    public int number;
}
```

Check this [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm), I hope it will help you.